# page title keeps changing between current and previous page flutter web

Tags: dart, flutter-web, flutter-getx

I'm having a weird issue changing page titles when using `getx` routing and navigation.

**Screenshot of the page title issue:**

[image]

im using this code to change page title :

```
void setPageTitle(String title, BuildContext context) {
      SystemChrome.setApplicationSwitcherDescription(ApplicationSwitcherDescription(
      label: title,
      primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.value, // This line is required
    ));
}
```

and it only happens when im using :

```
Get.toNamed(pageRoute);
```

this issue doesn't appear when im using :

```
Get.OffAllNamed(pageRoute);
```

Comment: I am unsure how to solve this but it likely only appears when using `Get.toNamed()` rather than `Get.offAllNamed()` because `offAllNamed()` pops the back stack, assuming that LogIn/Register was the previous page in the gif you shared.

Comment: you are right, either login or register is the previous page but i still cant figure out a solution